# Use SplitProcessor with space as delimiter in typoscript setup?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

How do I specify a space as the delimiter using SplitProcessor?

I want to be able to loop over each word from the header field:

```
20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\SplitProcessor
20 {
    delimiter = 
    fieldName = header
    as = words
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for `SplitProcessor` are run though `stdWrap`, so you can use `char` to set it to a space character:

```
20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\SplitProcessor
20 {
    delimiter.char = 32
    fieldName = header
    as = words
}
```

32 is the asci code for space.